# sending array as json to php script : returns empty array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i'm trying to send a form inputs as array to a php script

```
function submit_form(){
    var arr  =  [];
    var key, val ;
    $('#form input').each(function(){

        key = $(this).attr('id');
        val = $(this).val();
        arr[key] = val;

    })
    alert(arr['username']); // check to see if array is not empty

    var jsondata =  JSON.stringify(arr); 

    $.post(base_url+'profile/edit_profile/<?php echo $profile_username; ?>' , {data : jsondata }, function(){
    })
}
```

on the php script

```
$data =  json_decode($_post['data']);
var_dump($data);
exit;
```

and here is the result

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: Have you tried turning `{data: ...}` into `{"data": ...}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an Array when you should be using an Object.

```
var obj = {};
var key, val ;
$('#form input').each(function(){

    key = $(this).attr('id');
    val = $(this).val();
    obj[key] = val;

});
```

JSON methods will ignore non-numeric properties of Arrays.

---

Although instead of using `id` attributes, use `name`, and then use `.serialize()`.

```
var data = $('#form input').serialize();
```

Comment: thanx , i thought using serialize whould give me a string of "k&v" pears and it used for GET  method ?

Comment: @max: If you want an object structure, you can use `serializeArray()`, which will give you an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

This needs basic debugging first. Before you decode the data, dump it so you do ensure that the data is correct:

```
$data =  $this->input->post('data');
var_dump($data);
$array = json_decode($data);
var_dump($array);
exit;
```

Lessons to learn:

- Do one step after the other. The more stupid the better.
- Before and after each step, verify the data.